# How to SELECT an entire row using MAX()?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

So basically I have a table with two fields, 'number' and 'title', and I need a query to select the row with the highest value in 'number', for this i used

```
SELECT MAX('number') FROM table
```

Now I need to get the value of 'title' that corresponds to the highest value of 'number'.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql This has probably been solved before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by the `number` in descending order and return only one record with `limit`

```
select title
from your_table
order by number desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select title, number from table where number=(select max(number) from table);
```

Comment: this is human nature..  "make simple things more complex"